# decode this regex

Tags: sql, regex, string, oracle

I've tried to understand the below but don't seem to get the last part of the regular expression which has `{1,40}`. Overall, I know the pattern tries to match the special characters and something else (the {1,40})

```
regexp_like(COLUMN,'^['||UNISTR('\0020')||'-'||UNISTR('\0060')||UNISTR('\007B')||UNISTR('\007D')||UNISTR('\007E')||UNISTR('\00C0')||'-'||UNISTR('\00DF')||']'||'{1,40}$')
```

Comment: It's a quantifier. The preceeding token (a character class here) will be repeated 1 to 40 times.

Comment: '||' is putting me off which is right before {1,40}, and so I was not able to confirm my understanding. to me this seemed like an OR condition. So is this still a quantifier for the preceding character class? I am not trying to challenge, but I still have this doubt.

Comment: The `||` is the SQL string concatenation operator - it's not part of the regexp.

Comment: `||` is string concatenation in Oracle. `"[a-z]"||"{1,40}"` is equivalent to `"[a-b]" + "{1,40}"` in Java or `"[a-b]" . "{1,40}"` in PHP

Comment: amazing. I fully understand it now. Thank you all for the quick resolution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`regexp_like()` checks that a string matches the regex provided as second argument.

Your regexp looks like `^[...]{1,40}$`.

- `^` is the beginning of the string and `$` is the end, so the entire string must match the regex.
- `[...]` is a character class, that contains a bunch of characters code points. All characters of the string must belong to that list (any other character is forbiden). You would need to to check what they correspond to: [unicode.org](https://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp) is your friend. For the first code points:

```
    \0020    space
    \0060    grave accent
    \007B    left curly bracket
```

- finally, `{1,40}` is a quantifier: the length of the string must be at least one and at most 40.